# KeyPress event blocks KeyUp event in DataGridView .net

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview, c#-3.0, keyboard-events

I want to divide 30 whole apples between 10people in a DataGridView.
The DataGridView lies in a form that have KeyPreview set to true. The names of the people is displayed in a DataGridViewTextBoxColumn(*Column1*) that is set to readonly. The integers will then be entered in a empty DataGridViewTextBoxColumn(*Column2*). 
When a key is released the sum is calcuated/recalculated and if the sum of column2 is 30 then the form OK button is enabled(*else disabled*).

The problems is regarding the keyEvents. If a bind the KeyPress event the KeyUp is not triggered.

```
    // Bind events to DataGridViewCell
    private void m_DataGridView_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control != null)
        {
            e.Control.KeyUp -= m_DataGridView_KeyUp;
            e.Control.KeyPress -= m_DataGridView_KeyPress;
            e.Control.KeyUp += m_DataGridView_KeyUp;
            e.Control.KeyPress += m_DataGridView_KeyPress;
        }
    }

    //Only accept numbers
    private void m_GridView_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.KeyChar >= 48 && e.KeyChar <= 57) || e.KeyChar == 8)
        {
            e.Handled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

   // Sum the apples in column2
   private void m_DataGridView_KeyUp(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 1 && e.RowIndex > 0)
        {
            int count = 0;
            int parser = 0;

            foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.m_DataGridView.Rows)
            {
                if (item.Cells[1].Value != null)
                {
                    int.TryParse(item.Cells[1].Value.ToString(), out parser);
                    count += parser;
                }
            }

            //make the ok button enabled
            m_buttonDividedApplen.Enabled = (count == 30);
        }
    }
```

This story problem get stranger and stranger. If I switch cell then the keyup event get triggered. Sometimes the keyup gets trigger ONE time.

Comment: KeyUp is not executing always or only when you handled it at keypress?

Comment: KeyUp is only executing if KeyPress is not attached.

Answer (score 0):

You're re-attaching the handler to the same event every time the editing control fires, which is never changing, I believe.

I think if you stepped through your code, you'd notice the KeyPress event would get fired directly proportional to how many times you edit a cell. Try removing the handler first:

```
    e.Control.KeyUp -= m_DataGridView_KeyUp;
    e.Control.KeyPress -= m_DataGridView_KeyPress;
```

then re-attaching:

```
    e.Control.KeyUp += m_DataGridView_KeyUp;
    e.Control.KeyPress += m_DataGridView_KeyPress;
```

and see if KeyUp fires.

Comment: Well I have tried that also. The result is exactly the same. Reattaching of the handlers doesn't change the outcome.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry that didn't help. Still, you should probably not re-attach the handler in succession like that, as your KeyPress event will fire multiple times unintentionally.

Comment: Also, I'm unclear as to why you have the KeyPreview of the main form enabled. Wouldn't it be OK to just attach the handlers to the datagrid at design time and not handle the key press events at the form level?

Comment: According to a lot of posts the KeyPreview must be enabled to have the keys registering in DataGridView but according to my tests it doesn't make any difference.